# Can HTML5 Web Audio be as high quality as a DAW?

Tags: javascript, audio, tone.js

This question is mainly geared towards audio engineers.

I was looking at a few videos [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PN8Eg1K9xjE) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0MigafMWLh0) concerning the Web Audio API in javascript and how people are using it to make music. I was wondering can this API be used to create sound quality on the level of existing Digital Audio Workstations (DAWs) like Ableton, FL Studio, Reason, Logic, etc.

Or is there some kind of inherent limitation to the browser? I think VSTs cannot be used by Web Audio API, but regardless of VSTs is there something that an audio engine used by DAWs can do that Web Audio cannot do in terms of quality? Or can the sound be just as good. I believe that samples can be played just as effectively (?), but maybe the synthesis would be limited?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can HTML5 Web Audio be as high quality as a DAW?

Yes!  Browsers use a high quality audio engine, with floating point samples all the way through.

Additionally, the API itself is one of the most straightforward to use and is quite extensible.  It also supports very specific timing of control.

> I think VSTs cannot be used by Web Audio API

That is correct.

> but maybe the synthesis would be limited?

There are no real fundamental limitations.  If you can code it, you can do it.

Now, there are a couple things you didn't ask about but still should know about.  The first is an issue of latency.  Browsers don't use ASIO or anything like that, so if you're using the Web Audio API to process and return low latency audio, you're going to have a bad time.  In Chrome, you can improve this by letting Chrome open the audio device in exclusive mode.

Another issue is input/output channel count.  This typically maxes out at 8 channels.  Internally though, you can do pretty much whatever you want.  The limitation is from the browser, not the Web Audio API itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I could potentially have several midi and audio tracks playing back simultaneously with no noticeable latency? I'm not looking for alot, maybe 8 tracks where each track could be of either audio or midi. Also I'm hoping it can use the microphone for recording an audio track? and I'm guessing if there's no VSTs then the synthesized sounds might be lacking (?)

Comment: @foreyez What do you mean, "no noticeable latency"?  As I just said in my answer, there's definitely latency.  (And, there is *no* software solution that has "no noticeable latency", full DAW software or otherwise.)  Yes, you can have MIDI support and several audio tracks.  And, yes, you can use a microphone or any audio input device to record input.  While there is no plugin standard that I know of, there are plenty of synthesizers made with the Web Audio API.

Comment: But note that if you need a reliable click, you're out of luck, which makes input recording and output triggering rather imprecise. Using requestAnimationFrame will (typically) only give you 60 ticks per second, setInterval will at best get you 200~250, and _neither_ is reliable in that it's throttled by the rest of your code. Even if you abuse the event loop to get the highest possible timer running in web workers, you still end up with incidental stutter that completely ruins whatever you were trying to do, if what you were trying to do requires precise timing/interval.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I've been following your discussion over on the Web Audio Github:  https://github.com/WebAudio/web-midi-api/issues/232#issuecomment-1065615951  We *do* have a way to accurately time MIDI by setting a timestamp on output, but it isn't great because there's no clearing of the buffer, and no absolute timestamp.  We *do* have accurate audio triggering as well.

Comment: Yeah, there's still ways to go - don't get me wrong, there's lots of amazing things you can do right now (and you can _absolutely_ abuse the JS event system to get a higher fidelity, if still unpredictable intervalic timer ;) but it's not "DAW" levels of reliable/capable.

Answer (score 2):

There are some high quality audio applications that could run in the browser, but you can only do realtime audio in Chromium-based browsers, and you can't get realtime input even then.

Only Chromium supports high-priority audio threads in Audio Worklets, which you need for stable, realtime audio.

The WebMIDI API only runs on the main thread, which makes it useless for realtime input.

The WebUSB API is threadable, but does not permit communication with audio-class devices (which includes MIDI controllers (and soundcards)).

Keyboard, touch and mouse events must (currently) be handled by the main thread.

So, in short, you have no (practical) way to *control* realtime audio in Chromium, and cannot even do realtime audio (reliably) on any other platform.

---

**Note**: Adding support for WebMIDI workers was requested nine years ago, and the issue is still open (just for adding it to the spec).

**Note**: Electron will allow you to access protected USB device classes (Audio/MIDI), but Electron WebUSB support is still in progress. NWJS has WebUSB support, but no way to access protected device classes (though I opened an issue recently). WebUSB will work on these platforms eventually, but you would still need to implement web drivers for your controllers (even class-compliant ones), so this will not be an ideal solution, even once it it works.

Comment: UPDATE: The WebMIDI API maintainers have said they're optimistic about adding support for workers (to the spec) some time this year (2023). Electron now has WebUSB support, but there are still some things they need to iron out there.